# QooxDoo: Is there is any contribute for "Auto Completion" in Form Elements

Tags: qooxdoo

I am new to QooDoo, Now i am developing a web application in QooxDoo and PHP, This application has multiple forms.

It'll very use full if qooxdoo has a "auto complete" feature in its form elements  like TextField, ComboBox, SelectBox etc..

Is there is any library avaliable to implement auto-completion in qooxdoo ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The qooxdoo framework and the qooxdoo contributions do not offer such a feature. But using a combobox and data binding give you good tools to implement that yourself.

Comment: thanks martin. sorry for the late replay. I did autocomplete with ComboTable contrib. Thanks for the good lib.

Answer (score 0):

link to ComboTable 
http://demo.qooxdoo.org/contrib/demobrowser/#ComboTable~trunk%2Fdefault%2F1.4.2%2Findex.html

...............................................................................